# How to update collection data for collection of ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting collection of ids `[1,2,3,4]` in the `params` and I make a call to an API that will return the array for the corresponding ids. E.g. `["Apple","Orange","Mango"]`. How can I update this in my database for the corresponding ids?

For example: the `ids` which are mentioned above are from my user table. `ids = [1,2,3,4]`, which are primary keys in my user table.

From the API response I got an array of `fruit_names` for the correlated `user_ids`. E.g.: `ids = [1,2,3,4]` and `fruit_names = ["a","b","c","d"]`, where the `fruit_name` column exists in my user table. How do I update `fruit_name` from the API response correlated `ids` in my user table?

Comment: You have to give more details about what you're trying to do. We don't know what your database looks like. Also, please show us what you tried and where you're stuck exactly.

Comment: So how does this API call work exactly? Do you have any idea how `["Apple","Orange","Mango"]` relates to `[1,2,3,4]`? If you cannot make that clear in your question, it cannot be answered.

Comment: i have updated my question.Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`each_with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) in combination with [`update`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class) for this:

```
ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
  User.update(id, :fruit_name, fruit_names[index])
end
```

The above code assumes:

```
ids = [1,2,3,4]
fruit_names = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

and that the indexes of those arrays match.

Note that this will execute a query for each item in your `ids` array. If your `ids` array is very big this is not going to perform well.

Comment: @Mano There is probably no way to this in one query. The format of your update will always be `UPDATE users SET fruit_name = 'Apple' WHERE id = 1`, so there is no way to update multiple rows with different values in one query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[ids.zip fruit_names].each do |id, fruit|
  User.update_all({:fruit_name => fruit}, {:id => id})
end
```

OR

```
User.where(:id => ids).each do |usr|
 usr.update_attribute(:fruit_name, fruit_names[ids.index(usr.id)])
end
```